# bash - record output after program execution

Tags: ubuntu, bash, stdout

I know that I can redirect `stdout` to a file before running a script, but is there a way to access the whole output of a program that already ran? When the output is too long it gets cut out by the terminal window and I can't see the initial prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions:

1. increase the number of retained lines in your terminal window.  On all of the systems I can, I usually have it set to something like 10,000 lines (or the max possible is less).
2. (probably slightly more practical) When you know you might want to be able to capture output, start a new bash shell running and pipe the output to a file with tee (`bash | tee record.txt`).  Any output from commands run in that shell will be put into the file "record.txt".  Unfortunately, it does not capture input (including the commands you type) and shell prompts.
3. (better) Before executing anything you think you might want to safe, use `script`.  This will start capturing both your input and program output.  When you are finished with stuff, exit the shell or type Ctrl-D.  *Note:* the output generated by script may not be written until 'script' is finished.

Comment: You can use the `script` command to capture everything, including prompts and user-input. Adding it to your .profile might be a step too far though.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Cool, I learned something new today!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. So if I run the script without any of these options, everything that goes off the screen is lost forever. Is this correct? I thought that the output could be saved somewhere (for example, `bash_history` automatically records what I write).